# Replace Circles and Texts in d3 demo with foreignObject containing custom HTML and ko binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, d3.js

Given [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/tU5zN/) which is an exact copy of [this d3 demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292), I would like to replace the circle and text elements in the SVG with foreignObject elements which contain some custom HTML.

I was able to manually add one using the following code:

```
var newFO = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "foreignObject");
$('svg').append(newFO);
$(newFO).append("<div class='test'>" + strNameVar + "</div>");
```

([fiddle with this implemented](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/tU5zN/1/))

But it's not part of the graph, obviously.  I really don't understand d3 enough to insert these on the fly using the "links" dataset in the demo.  Basically I need to adapt the following code to use a foreignObject instead of a text element and then insert the custom HTML:

```
var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
```

**update**:
[This version of the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/tU5zN/5/) is the closest I've come, but it's applying the transform to the div instead of the parent foreignObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by appending the `g` elements first and then the `foreignObject` elements below. Like this (in a slight abuse of selectors):

```
var node = svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
    .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("g");
node.append("foreignObject")
    // etc
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tU5zN/6/).